# Where Is Opera Plug-ins Database?

Tags: flash, opera

In Opera 12 for the PC, you can see the plug-in used for .SWF files by clicking Tools/Preferences/Downloads/{find .SWF}/Edit...

The path & file ("npswf32.dll") pointed to by Opera exists on my hard drive, but I cannot change that filename or path within Opera.  Does anyone know whether I could manually/programmatically edit a file where Opera stores this information?  I'd like to be able to change Flash plug-ins with a quick restart of Opera versus an entire re-install of Flash.

Comment: You might find more help with this on superuser.com

Comment: Thank you; I'll give it a try.